# Prevent Visual Studio 2010 attempting remote debugging of a web service

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm working on a library in Visual Studio 2010 that consumes a third party web service as a web reference (not a WCF service reference).

When running in debug mode, if a developer steps into one of the web methods provided by the third party web service Visual Studio will try and attach a remote debugger and step into the server. As expected, this fails.

> Unable to automatically step into the server. Connection to the server machine 'XYZ' failed. The debugger cannot connect to the remote computer. This may be because the remote computer does not exist or a firewall may be preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance.

[image: Visual Studio Debugger attempting to step into a third party web service]

How can I indicate to the Visual Studio 2010 debugger that is shouldn't attempt to step into this web service?

The easiest approach would be for developers to step over the applicable lines rather than into them, but I'd like to find a more reliable solution.

I've tried using the [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden] and [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough] attributes on the methods that invoke the web methods but the error still occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using.

[DebuggerStepThrough()]

see 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx

Comment: I did try that as I mentioned in the last paragraph but Visual Studio is still attempting to debug the remote server.